# How to create CIFS docker volume with username, password, uid, and gid

Tags: docker, cifs

I am trying to create docker volumes using the **docker-volume-netshare** driver from here: https://github.com/ContainX/docker-volume-netshare

The sequence should be like this:

```
docker volume create -d cifs <some_options>
docker run -v <the_volume> <other_docker_options>
```

and I can get it to work part of the way but for the life of me I can't get it to pass all the options I need.

Instead of trying to recount my countless different failure modes, I would prefer to state my goal. Underneath, docker-volume-netshare will execute a `mount -t cifs ...` command. This can be seen in the log when `verbose` is set to `true`.

This is the mount command that I am trying to get. I can get username and password in there, but only when using a .netrc file, and I have found no way to get the uid and gid into the command.

```
mount -t cifs -o username=myusername,password=mypasswd,uid=500,gid=499,rw //myserver.example.net/mysharename /the_mount_point/
```

So what I am looking for is the authoritative syntax for passing these options through docker-volume-netshare.

Comment: What did the developers say when you opened an issue on github?

Comment: I have not opened an issue on Github, because I thought that the issue tracker is for bug reports and feature requests, not requests for support. So far I am still thinking that I just need to learn how to do it right.

Comment: You should have opened an issue first, before coming here. Plus, this looks at first glance like missing functionality, which would require someone to implement.

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to determine that this looks like missing functionality. Are you saying that when I have a question/support request for a software product I should first open an issue on the issue tracker of that software? And if I have not done that, then my question is not welcome on serverfault? I know of some software projects where that approach would not be appreciated. Well, I guess it is just hard to please everyone!

Comment: This is a site for IT professionals, and as such we expect you to have done a minimum of attempting to resolve problems on your own.

Comment: I apologize for insulting you with my substandard question. You are a moderator, so please feel free to close my question. I will remember to bother the developers of a project first next time before I take the time of serverfault readers.

Answer (score 7):

A little bit late ...
But here is the solution:

```
docker volume create \
     --driver local \
     --opt type=cifs \
     --opt device=//server.domain/path/to/share \
     --opt o=addr=server.domain,username=myuser,password=mypw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 \
     --name myvolume
```

In some situations the DNS-name did not work, this has been fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/39250#issuecomment-765172947) and now domain names can be used by adding **addr** in the CIFS options.
Using the option "credentials" instead of "username" an "password" did not work for me. I'm getting always the error "No username specified". From the shell (mount -t cifs //server/path -o credentials=/etc/cifs.cred /tmp/mnt) it works fine.

Comment: Did you find out in what situations the hostname resolution didn't work?

Comment: hi Jack, i have made an edit to the answer, needs to be approved by dmaj. You need to use the addr option (in the line where options are defined o= ) and specify the domain there. Docker will perform a getaddr from it and resolve the domain